Kotlin multiplatform apple framework on watchos simulator
After adding watchosArm64 and watchosSimulatorArm64 to my multiplatform project, I get the following error in xcode when running the ios or watchos app
Ignoring file '/path/to/my/project/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/watchsimulator10.5/MyProject.framework/MyProject': fat file missing arch 'x86_64', file has 'arm64'
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I’m running xcode from a M1 macbook, I shouldn’t need watchosX64 right? If I do add it, then the project fails to compile due to other libraries not supporting it. In my case it's the apollo library.
